# Use tm_filter to search for multiple words

Tags: text-mining, filter

I´m new to R, so please bear with me.

So, I know I can use the following to search for a word in several documents.

```
data("crude")
tm_filter(crude, FUN = function(x) any(grep("company", content(x))))
```

How do I search for more? I´m thinking I can write a for-loop, but I´m guessing there is some smarter way..?

Comment: Welcome to R!  You want to search for more words or across more documents?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. I want to search more words.

Comment: Would something along the line of regex for multiple words work? i.e. "company|corporate"

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in the **quanteda** package easily using the `kwic()` function.  For the crude corpus from tm, for instance, you can do the following:

```
devtools::install_github("kbenoit/quanteda", quiet = TRUE)
require(quanteda)
data(crude, package = "tm")
mycorpus <- corpus(crude)
kwic(mycorpus, "company")
##                                    contextPre keyword                     contextPost
##  [127, 67]                     oil market," a company spokeswoman said. Diamond is   
##  [194, 64]                    dlrs a bbl. The company last changed its crude postings
## [236, 345] challenge to any international oil company that declared Kuwait sold below
##  [543, 71]                 to 16.35 dlrs, the company said. No changes were          
##  [543, 91]                  of crude oil, the company said. Reuter
```

Note that here I have also included the installation command to get the latest version of **quanteda** from GitHub, since when I answered this post, the version (0.8.5-7) required to convert a **tm** `VCorpus` object correctly was not yet on CRAN.  (Apparently the structure of a `VCorpus` object has changed recently.)

Note also that the references in brackets are the document name (in `crude`, these are just numbers) and the token serial number where the keyword occurs in the text.

Comment: I think that the question was-and I also would be interested in the answer- how to find a conjonction of keywords (e.g. `company`and `market`)